# Is doing a PhD equivalent to studying for an undergraduate diploma?

Tags: phd, undergraduate

Can a person do PhD with same knowledge as that of undergraduate level.

Comment: Sure, if a university's standard is low.  I've had faculty members from some countries with a 'PhD' email me wanting to do a post-doc.  However, their PhD thesis is at the level of my university's undergraduate theses.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking if one can do a Ph.D. without getting a Master's first? Or if doing a Master's can give you enough knowledge to start a ph.D. in case you did not have a Bachelor's degree?

Answer (score 2):

Almost everywhere, much more is expected of doctoral students that is expected of undergraduates.

There are a few places with such low standards that the above "rule" isn't followed. There are a few students who have studied so hard and attained so much as an undergraduate that doctoral studies seem to be about the same. But both of these are rare.

In the US, at least, doctoral studies include advanced courses that may not be available to undergraduates and they are expected to do well in them.

Moreover, few undergraduates have sufficient knowledge or experience to do an acceptable dissertation.

So, the answer for most is no, you need to go beyond. Perhaps far beyond. The answer for a few, very few, I think, might be yes. There are, in fact, people who complete undergraduate studies at around age 13. Very rare. Sadly, some of those exceptional people burn out.

---

Note a couple of things. In many places a masters degree (not a PhD) can be very similar to undergraduate studies. Courses, exams, papers, grades. Other places research is also required.

Also note that getting a doctorate isn't an ability you are born with. It is something you do. It takes hard work and, I think, most people can do it if they put their mind to it, starting with undergraduate studies. It is a lot of work. Hard work. But it can be learned.